# JComboBox returning double value

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I started making a small application where the user is required to select their province from a combobox, I added an action listener to the combobox. I wanted to test the `ActionListener` so I just made it print what was selected to the console. For some reason it seems as though I am getting the value of the combobox returned twice. For example, I select "Alberta" on the combobox, "Alberta Alberta" is printed to the console. Anyone have any idea why this might be?

```
JComboBox comboProv = new JComboBox(provinces);
        comboProv.setBounds(40, 79, 137, 24);
        contentPane.add(comboProv);
        comboProv.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                String selectedProv = (String)comboProv.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.print(selectedProv);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't add an `ActionListener`, you add a `ItemListener`, a `ItemListener` will be notified twice when the value changes, once for the `ItemEvent.DESELECTED` event and once for the `ItemEvent.SELECTED`.

If you're not interested in the change of selection simply use a `ActionListener`

```
comboProv.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String selectedProv = (String)comboProv.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.print(selectedProv);
    }
});
```

Which will only be notified once

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Great thanks , never even realized. Just getting back into this after a while so I am rusty.

Answer (score 1):

put this inside the listener.. It printed twice because it is called for `selected` and `deselected`.. so add this to filter

```
if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
               String selectedProv = (String)comboProv.getSelectedItem();
               System.out.print(selectedProv);.
    } else if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
                //Do any operations you need to do when an item is de-selected.
    }
```